# How to create checkbox inputs for an array of objects in React with Zod schema and use React hook form?

Tags: validation, next.js, input, react-hook-form, zod

I'm using React hook form and Zod for form validation. I have a Zod schema for an array of objects, where each object represents an add-on service with a name and a price. Here's the schema:

```
addOns: z.array(
    z.union([
      z.object({
        name: z.literal("Online service"),
        price: z.enum(["1", "10"]),
      }),
      z.object({
        name: z.literal("Larger storage"),
        price: z.enum(["2", "20"]),
      }),
      z.object({
        name: z.literal("Customizable Storage"),
        price: z.enum(["2", "20"]),
      }),
    ])
  ),
});
```

I want to create a checkbox input for each add-on in the addOns array. When a checkbox is checked, the corresponding add-on object should be added to the addOns array in the form data. When a checkbox is unchecked, the corresponding add-on object should be removed from the addOns array.

this is for the reference of what I want:
[wanted_Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrZMx.png)

if checkbox for online service is checked then the object

```
{ name: "Online service", price: billing === "Monthly" ? "1" : "10" }
```

[if checkbox is checked:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRX3m.png)
is added to addOns and removed if unchecked.
same applies to the other checkboxes.

This is what I tried to do:

```
const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setValue("addOns.0", {
      name: "Online service",
      price: billing === "Monthly" ? "1" : "10",
    });
    register("addOns");
  };
```

```
<input
                  {...register("addOns")}
                  name="addOns"
                  id="online"
                  className="rounded-checkbox checked:accent-purplish-blue w-5 h-5 border-[1px] border-light-gray border-solid"
                  type="checkbox"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
```

I do not know if this is the best way to solve the problem. If there's any I would really welcome it Thank you..